# Convert String to TextInputType Flutter

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I want to convert String to TextInputType datatype in Flutter

I was uploading every textformfield's input type to firestore, but it doesnt accept TextInputType as a datatype, so i converted it to String

Can somebody tell how to Convert String to TextInputType

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a custom method that would do that. For example you could have something like this which will convert your string to the corresponding type of the input:

```
TextInputType textInputTypeFromString(String input) {
  switch (input) {
    case 'text':
      return TextInputType.text;
    case 'multiline':
      return TextInputType.multiline;
    case 'number':
      return TextInputType.number;
    case 'phone':
      return TextInputType.phone;
    case 'datetime':
      return TextInputType.datetime;
    case 'emailAddress':
      return TextInputType.emailAddress;
    case 'url':
      return TextInputType.url;
    case 'visiblePassword':
      return TextInputType.visiblePassword;
    default:
      return TextInputType.text;
  }
}
```

Another option would be to have a map instead of using this switch, with the string as keys and the TextInputType as values and access that directly:

```
final Map<String, TextInputType> inputTypeMap = {
  'text': TextInputType.text,
  'multiline': TextInputType.multiline,
  'number': TextInputType.number,
  'phone': TextInputType.phone,
  'datetime': TextInputType.datetime,
  'emailAddress': TextInputType.emailAddress,
  'url': TextInputType.url,
  'visiblePassword': TextInputType.visiblePassword,
};

TextInputType textInputTypeFromString(String input) {
  return inputTypeMap[input] ?? TextInputType.text;
}
```